# Recognize BREAK in protocol reliable (RS232)

Tags: c#, serial-port

i have an EMS bus on RS232 with a protocol where all blocks are seperated with a BREAK(0x00).

The Data is send continuously from the device.

My problem is, that I'm not able to seperated this blocks reliable.

In a block is sometimes a 0x00 (but this is no break).

I know that every block starts with 0x01,0x02 or 0x03 and ends with a CRC+BREAK.

Is there a good way to split the blocks in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot implement a protocol with Break.  It is meant as an asynchronous interrupt signal, it bypasses the FIFO in most UART designs.  And the device driver input buffer.  You'll need to scrap that plan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an RS232 break, our just a zero byte being transmitted?

It sounds like you are talking about a zero byte, in which case you need to tell the difference between a data byte and a terminator byte.

In this case, you need to look at identifying features of the data packets. If the packets are always the same length, then you can easily tell if the zero is a terminator. otherwise you'll need to parse the data in the packets to work it out. Do they contain any kind of length information? Or perhaps you have to read the data byte by byte and parse it to work out what each byte means, and thus where the packet ends.

If you can't do this then you don't have a protocol, you have random unpredictable data. Any protocol must allow some way for you to detect and split the packets.